# hdfs delete a file being written

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Acording the [blog](https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/02/understanding-hdfs-recovery-processes-part-1/), hdfs uses the lease mechanism to avoid two client writing the same file. So I think one can not delete the file which is written by the other client. Howerver, it's wrong.

When client A is writing the  lock.txt, client B can delete lock.txt immediately. Client A can continue writing although the file no longer exists. Just when closing the stream, A will encounter the exception:

 `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.LeaseExpiredException: No lease on /user/lock.txt (inode 643845185): File does not exist. Holder DFSClient_NONMAPREDUCE_-1636584585_1 does not have any open files**`

Why this happen? My haddop version is 2.7.3.

================================

This is my test code：

```
// write process
object Create {

  private val filePath = "/user/lock.txt"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Create start!")
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    val os = Option(fs.create(new Path(filePath), false))
    if (os.isDefined) {
      println(s"Create result! $os", System.currentTimeMillis())
      0.until(300).foreach(index => {
        os.get.write(100)
        os.get.flush()
        println("Writing...")
        Thread.sleep(1000)
      })
      println("pre close" + System.currentTimeMillis())
      os.get.close()
      println("close success!" + System.currentTimeMillis())
    }
  }

}

// delete process
object Delete {

  private val filePath = "/user/lock.txt"

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Delete start!")
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    while (!fs.exists(new Path(filePath))) {
      println("File no exist!")
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
    println("File exist!")
    while (true) {
      println("try delete!")
      val tmp = Option(fs.delete(new Path(filePath), false))
      if (tmp.isDefined) {
        println(s"delete result:${tmp.get}!" + System.currentTimeMillis())
      }
      println("Try recover")
      if (fs.asInstanceOf[DistributedFileSystem].recoverLease(new Path(filePath))) {
        println("Recover lease success!")
        val res = Option(fs.delete(new Path(filePath), false))
        println(s"File delete success:${res.get}")
      } else {
        println("Recover lease failed!")
      }
      Thread.sleep(1000)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: How exactly were you performing a write operation in HDFS?

Comment: @Abhinav Code has been added. Please see if there is a problem

Comment: I am not good with codes. I can tell you about the architecture as I'm in administration part and It is not possible to write a file by one client and delete the same from another client. Because HDFS write anatomy shares exclusive lock property and multiple reads are possible but not writes. There may be some error on your end. But it is not possible in real life scenario

Comment: @Abhinav It should be the same as what you said, but the actual test is not, so I do not understand. Anyway, thank you.